# Use of string resources in enum and use in switch case

Tags: java, android

I have a requirement where i have to use string from resources in android to support different languages .
Switch case is not taking string as constant from resources.
Like R.string.example

So i have to use enums.Need an example to use enums constant using string resources in android and using it in Switch case

Comment: R.string.example is an int and can be used with switch case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enums` are userdefine constants so you cannot compare them with resources (you can then it will be like assigning a string value to enums and compare them using equal function with String resourece value) which is kind of a lengthy so avoid it.

You can use string with switch with java 1.7+ though android manages a unique `int` id of every resource in xml so you can add you switch case string inputs into resource 'strings.xml' and use like int

```
switch (stringResourceID) {
case R.string.first_string:
     break;
case R.string.second_string:
     break;
case R.string.third_string:
     break;
default:
     break;
}
```

You can also create you constant with 'public static final string ' and use them as case label , you should declare constants like this in a separate file to make them easily accessible

```
public static final String C1="first";
public static final String C2="second";
public static final String C3="third";


    switch (yourInputString) {
    case C1:
         break;
    case C2:
         break;
    case C3:
         break;
    default:
         break;
    }
```

[image: example]

Comment: my requirement is to use string from resources folder.i can not use R.string.third_string in case statement it gives compilation error.

Comment: you must be doing something wrong. lemme add a screenshot to show